# Can the BaseFieldOverride class be used to implement hook_entity_bundle_info()?

Tags: 8, entities

I need to implement [`hook_entity_bundle_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info/8.2.x), and I noticed that the documentation includes a link to [Finalize API for creating, overriding, and altering code-defined bundle fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2346347). In short, that issue says that is wrong to use the [`BaseFieldDefinition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/class/BaseFieldDefinition/8.2.x) class because that class marks the field as a base field, which is not true, since the field is being added to a bundle.

Can the [`BaseFieldOverride`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Entity%21BaseFieldOverride.php/class/BaseFieldOverride/8.2.x) class be used to implement `hook_entity_bundle_info()`?

Doing so, the example given for `hook_entity_bundle_info()` would become the following one.

```
function hook_entity_bundle_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle, array $base_field_definitions) {
  // Add a property only to nodes of the 'article' bundle.
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node' && $bundle == 'article') {
    $fields = [];
    $base_field_definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('More text'))
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setClass('\Drupal\mymodule\EntityComputedMoreText');
    $fields['mymodule_text_more'] = BaseFieldOverride::createFromBaseFieldDefinition($base_field_definition, $bundle);
    return $fields;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the issue you linked](https://www.drupal.org/node/2346347) the answer is **no**:

> So, in theory, contrib modules can implement non-config-based bundle fields, but we don't provide an implementation class with which to do so.

Comment: The issue is still marked *Needs work*, but there haven't been new patches since 2017.